# Y86 code doesn't handle ret instruction as expected

Tags: assembly, x86, y86

The following is a homework problem for an assembly language class.  We're to create Y86 code by reading X86 code generated from C in gdb.  The purpose of the function is to sum the elements of a linked list.

As the function currently stands, it works!   The correct value is contained in the %eax register when the program terminates.  Unfortunately, it is only correct due to a hack.  I added a `halt` instruction right at the end of the function, right before the `ret` instruction.  If I uncomment that, what appears to happen is that when it carries out the `ret` instruction, the PC is set to 0x0.  In other words, it seems to start over at the beginning, when what it *should* do is return to the point where it was called.  It enters an infinite loop.

The code follows.  It is standalone, if you have the Y86 simulator installed.

```
.pos    0
init:    irmovl Stack, %esp  
irmovl    Stack, %ebp  
jmp     Main  

Main:  
    irmovl  ele1, %eax  
    pushl   %eax  
    call    sum_list  
    halt  

sum_list:  
    pushl   %ebp  
    rrmovl  %esp, %ebp  
    irmovl  $16, %edx  
    subl    %edx, %esp  
    irmovl  $0, %edx  
    rmmovl  %edx, -4(%ebp)  
    jmp     L2  

L3:
    mrmovl  8(%ebp), %eax
    mrmovl  (%eax), %eax
    mrmovl  -4(%ebp), %edx
    addl    %eax, %edx
    rmmovl  %edx, -4(%ebp)
    mrmovl  8(%ebp), %eax
    mrmovl  4(%eax), %eax
    rmmovl  %eax, 8(%ebp)

L2:
    irmovl  $0, %ecx
    mrmovl  8(%ebp), %edx
    subl    %ecx, %edx
    jne     L3
    mrmovl  -4(%ebp), %eax
    rrmovl  %esp, %ebp
    popl    %ebp
    halt #THIS DOESN'T BELONG. COMMENT OUT TO SEE BAD BEHAVIOR.
    ret

#linked list
.align  4
    ele1:
            .long   0x00a
            .long   ele2
    ele2:
            .long   0x0b0
            .long   ele3
    ele3:
            .long   0xc00
            .long   0


    .pos    0x300
    Stack:
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not be the cause of the error, but I think you are tearing down the stack frame of `sum_list` incorrectly. You set it up as follows:

```
pushl   %ebp  
rrmovl  %esp, %ebp
```

but then you tear it down like this:

```
rrmovl  %esp, %ebp
popl    %ebp
```

Notice that you copy from `%esp` to `%ebp` in both cases, which is not correct since the teardown is supposed to undo what the setup does. Instead, try

```
rrmovl  %ebp, %esp
popl    %ebp
```

or simply

```
leave
```

which does the same thing.

Comment: thanks!  That was it.  My confusion stems from Y86 not having the leave instruction.  I looked up how that instruction worked and must've copied it in wrong.  I made the change and it works just fine!

Comment: @user373374: Splendid! By the way, I haven't heard about Y86 before - it seems to be a teaching language based on X86? Seems interesting; do you have any good resources about it?

Comment: Yes, it's a simplified assembly language for teaching.  wrt resources, it's mostly our textbook, Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective, authors Bryant & O'Hallaron, the class slides, and of course the Google :)  It's almost identical to X86, just with a smaller instruction set.  For instance, movl is broken up into rrmovl, rmmovl, mrmovl and irmovl (reg->reg, reg->mem, mem->reg and const->reg respectively).  You also have to decompose instructions like leave and lea.

Answer (score 0):

```
mrmovl  -4(%ebp), %edx
```

here is the problem. at ebp - 4 there is the return address, so you're overwriting it. Use a different location and everything will be fine :)

Comment: Shouldn't the return address be at ebp + 4?  Doesn't the stack grows in the direction of lower addresses (i.e., the top of the stack is really the bottom)?  So in this case, at call, return address is at esp.  Next instruction, old ebp is pushed (meaning %esp is dec'd by 4) and then ebp is moved to that value, meaning ebp is dec'd by 4 as well.  So ebp *should* be 4 *below* the return address.

Answer (score -1):

There are two (and a half) problems related to stack manipulations:

The frame is set up correctly, but the deconstruction piece fails (the program does rrmovl  %esp, %ebp instead of rrmovl  %ebp, %esp)

The attempt to access the parameter stored in the previous frame (i.e. the caller's frame) fails.  The stack runs from the top and down and the last elements stored on the stack are the return address and the old frame pointer, so once the ebp register has been changed, the callee can refer directly to the calling function’s arguments through progressive offset starting with 8(%ebp).

There half error is that the main function does not pop the stored parameter of the stack before it terminates.

The caller-callee convention is discussed on my Y86 blog at http://y86tutoring.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/functioning-stacks/